# UUID in JDL produces "error: cannot find symbol" in gateway

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I am trying to generate gateway+microservice apps in jhipster. Codegen completes fine but then the resulting app fails compilation with

```
R:\my-ms\gateway\src\main\java\com\my\domain\Practice.java:336: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setStaffId(UUID staff) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class UUID
  location: class Practice
18 errors
```

I am using this config:

```
application {
  config {
    baseName gateway
    applicationType gateway
    packageName com.my
    authenticationType jwt
    reactive false
    clientFramework react
    buildTool gradle
    serverPort 8080
  }
  entities * 
}

...

entity Practice {
    practiceName String
    address1 String
    address2 String
    city String
    state String
    zip String
}

entity Staff {
    id UUID
    jobtitle String
}


relationship OneToMany {
    Staff to Practice{staff}
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You should open an issue on github and don't forget to paste output of `jhipster info`. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues

Comment: Thank you for taking a look - that's what I thought - switching to String resolved the problem.

Comment: It did not resolve the problem, it worked around it.